# java setting font in jar file

Tags: java, netbeans, fonts, jar, truetype

I'm trying to set a font "bilboregular.ttf" found in the resources folder under the root of the jar file. If i run from netbeans the font is set successfully, however if from the jar file it isn't

CODE:

```
main method:{

        String s = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\resources\\" + "bilboregular.ttf";
        File a = new File(s);
        if (a.exists()) {
            this.loadFont(s);
        } else {
            this.loadFont(this.getClass().getResource("/resources/" + "bilboregular.ttf").getFile());
        }
}

 public void loadFont(String s) {
    try {
        font = java.awt.Font.createFont(java.awt.Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File(s));
        font = font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 20);
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        ge.registerFont(font);
        setFonts();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

}

public boolean setFonts() {
    jLabel3.setFont(font);
    jLabel4.setFont(font);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main can't use `getClass()` because its `static` (assuming you mean `public static void main(String args[])` with *"main"*).

Try this code:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/bilboregular.ttf");
Font f = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
```

if this doesn't work: please post the structure of your JAR and and the thrown exception (eg. use a Logger in your `catch` Block).
Btw. an empty exceptionblock is not a good idea here since IO operations can fail in many cases.

Comment: Passed the input stream for font creation as you said. It worked like that. Thanks

Comment: Great! :-) But if this was helpful or solved your problem, please mark as solved.